# JavaFX JDK not found

Tags: javafx, java

I'm trying to install JavaFX for the first time and it says that version 1.6.0 or higher is required but none found. Also when I load a JavaFX app in firefox or chrome it says it can't find Java. This is strange since I have 1.6.0_07-b06 installed and I actively use it for development.

Is there a certain place JavaFX looks? Is this a bug?

thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Sun recommends Java versions later than Java 6 update 10 for JavaFX as it takes advantage of the new applet re-working and various other bits. Try upgrading.

Let me know if that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: will do. they do recommend that but said it should work with update 7 or later. I didn't want to update since it's on my work PC, but I will try. thanks.

Comment: I updated and it worked. Seems bad that a user would need that recent of a Java version for JavaFX to work.

Comment: From what I gather it completely depends on what features the JavaFX app is trying to use from the platform. I have seen apps that work on Java 5 even but it just seems safest to go with the most recent version.

Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

are u on windows? if so make sure the environment variable >  PATH includes the path to the latest java instead of some old one

Comment: I am on Windows but it is in the path.

Comment: just make sure that it is the only reference to java in the path , cause sometimes u will have 2 paths to java in there and it would cause problems

Comment: if u have the path right and also have the JAVA_HOME etc setup then i am out of ideas .. best of luck with it.

Comment: yep, I've got them both setup (Sorry if my last comment seemed a little snide - I've tried the basics already though). still no luck. I've read other articles about some bugs so I could try getting a newer version of the JDK since update 11 is recommended.

Comment: no worries there .. i understand that when those kinda questions come through its hard to restraint.. its like when u call the broadband customer support and they ask u .. have u cleared your browser cache ? :) ... hope that the latest java version solves the issue

Comment: ha, thanks. ill give it a try (probably not today though) and post my results.